# How to use WebRTC APIs in Node.js without browser or any HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

So i'm making a command line application which will send text messages between two clients using WebRTC and Node.js with socket.io signalling. But when i'm using the RTCPeerConnection api there is this error :

```
myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { 
    ^

ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined
```

The code segment is :

```
var configuration = { 
    "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }] 
}; 

myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { 
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}] 
     }); 

     console.log("RTCPeerConnection object was created"); 
     console.log(myConnection); 

     //setup ice handling 
     //when the browser finds an ice candidate we send it to another peer 
     myConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) { 
        console.log("Ice candidates found");
        if (event.candidate) { 
           send({ 
              type: "candidate", 
              candidate: event.candidate 
           });
        } 
     };
```

But when I include this js file in an HTML file as a script then it works fine. Does it have something to with the fact that WebRTC is a browser API and doesn't work outside it? I really don't wanna use a library for WebRTC. What should I do to make use of WebRTC apis without a browser?

Answer (score 2):

It is mandatory to use a library for WebRTC in node. Why do you not want to use [wrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc)? It is the same exact API as the browser.

If you are willing to use other languages you could also do C/C++, Go or Python. I don't know of bindings in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I'm using wrtc now and the error is gone but there are new errors like the creaetDataChannel() method is not working, it says that the RTCPeerConnection's signalling state is 'closed'. I think wrtc has some things different than WebRTC but i can't find its doumentation anywhere not even on npm or github. Can you suggest me a source?

Comment: I could resolve the DataChannel error on my Mac by following steps: 
1. npm install -g node-pre-gyp 
2. npm install wrtc 
Provide correct STUN server in iceServers list

Comment: As of 2023 *wrtc* project is discontinued. Current alternatives are [node-datachannel](https://github.com/murat-dogan/node-datachannel) or [werift](https://github.com/shinyoshiaki/werift-webrtc)